# Windows Chrome keyboard shortcut for Bookmark Manager stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows, Chrome shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to access the Bookmark Manager periodically stops working.

The global shortcuts/hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> also do not work.

Comment: Does it work if you temporarily disable all plugins?

Comment: @miro It does not.

Comment: Do you think you can try your Chrome with new user profile? Also, I see someone complaining about the same Ctrl+Shift+O problem in January 2018, without any reply. If this is such a strange issue, you can try Chrome with new user profile or maybe re-installing of the Chrome browser? (profile and browser can be two different possible causes)

Comment: @miroxlav I tried with a new profile but had the same issue

Comment: @miroxlav figured it out, thanks for trying to troubleshoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that a few other shortcuts (registered with other applications) weren't working, either.

It turns out there's some kind of Radeon overlay running, a pair of processes called `amdow.exe` and `amddvr.exe`. This in spite of the fact that ReLive is **NOT** installed.

Three hotkeys are registered by default:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

---

One has two options for dealing with these processes:

1. ## Prevent the processes from loading

   Delete or rename `amdow.exe` and `amddvr.exe` in the `C:\Program Files\AMD\CNext\CNext\` directory. This will prevent them from being launched on boot or whenever Radeon Settings is opened.
2. ## Disable or change the hotkeys

   If you use ReLive, have a use for the overlay panel, or otherwise want to keep the processes intact for whatever reason, you might prefer to simply change or disable the hotkeys. You'll need to edit the Registry for this.

   The Registry keys `ToggleRsPerfUiHotkey`, `ToggleRsHotkey` and `ToggleRsPerfRecordingHotkey` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\AMD\DVR` register, by default, the hotkeys `control-shift-O`, `alt-R` and `control-shift-L`, respectively. You can edit the hotkeys or safely delete/rename the keys.

This is Radeon software version 17.12.2.

Comment: Ad 1: You can use Microsoft Sysinternals [Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to simply disable the exe from automatic launching instead of changing the files of existing installation what can have unpredictable results.

Comment: @miroxlav unfortunately, I don't think that will work since the executables are launched by Radeon Settings, not by Windows.

Comment: omg finally i figure out why its stopped working. i thought it was a chrome bug. there arent even options to disable radeon from starting up in task manager... retarded. i wonder if it restores the registry modifications at each boot?

Comment: now how do i restore the chrome hot key for the bookmark manager?!?!

Comment: reboot was all that was needed for the changes to take effect!

Comment: @user2230470 glad it helped someone else. This was personally driving me CRAZY.